# NSDateFormatter showing incorrect month

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

**Description:**

I'm using `NSDateFormatter` for formatting date but the output is wrong the month is getting changed and even the time is changing in some cases.

**Code:**

```
NSDate *date=[NSDate date];
NSString *datestring=@"2018-07-05 12:14:29";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];
date = [formatter dateFromString:datestring];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

**Expected Output:**

```
2018-07-05 12:14:29
```

**Output Got:**

```
2018-01-05 12:14:29
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DD` is `day of year`

`dd` is `day of month`

So replace below line

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];
```

by this

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```